# What does this mean: Symmetry of the KDV generated by a vector field

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-spaces, mathematical-physics, symmetry

What is

> a symmetry of the KDV 
>   $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=6u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3}$$ generated by $$V=A(t,x,u)\frac{\partial }{\partial t}+B(t,x,u)\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+C(t,x,u)\frac{\partial }{\partial u}$$?

I don't understand what that means. From class notes, I know that $$V=A(t,x,u)\frac{\partial }{\partial t}+B(t,x,u)\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+C(t,x,u)\frac{\partial }{\partial u}$$ generates a symmetry given by the set of ODEs 
$$\frac{d t}{d \epsilon}=A\\\frac{d x}{d \epsilon}=B\\\frac{d u}{d \epsilon}=C
$$
But I don't understand what

> "a symmetry of ... generated by V" means.

Could someone please explain?

Comment: I think I understand it now. I means the transformed variables  must preserve the kDV.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this statement means that the [continuous symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_symmetry) generated by the vector field $V$ preserves the PDE.